# Constructing central extensions or Schur cover of U4(3) in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Part of my group theory project involves we're looking at the group $U_4(3)$, which has abnormally large Schur Multiplier (36) and large automorphism group ($D_{12}$). I need to work with the central extensions by a group with order divisible by 3 in GAP: specifically, I would like the groups
$$3.U_4(3), 6.U_4(3), 12.U_4(3).$$
I know that GAP has the command SchurCover(), but it returns a finitely presented group which takes too long to convert to a permutation group. Any calculations with group extensions and TwoCohomologyGeneric take very long. Also, the order of these groups exceeds 2 million, and thus are not in the perfect group library, so I am out of ideas.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: You can find $3^2.U_4(3)$ as a subgroup of $3.Suz$. There is a permutation representation for $3.Suz$ at [https://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/Suz/](https://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/Suz/), you can then construct a maximal subgroup of $3.Suz$ which has derived subgroup $3^2.U_4(3)$. You can then use this to construct the two different extensions $3.U_4(3)$. The other extensions you mention I don't know.

Comment: $4.U_4(3)$ is just ${\rm SU}(4,3)$, which has a permutation representation of degree $2160$. You can combine that with each of the two groups $3.U_4(3)$ to get the two groups $12.U_4(3)$.

Comment: You  can get a group with structure $3^2.U_4(3).D_8$ from the ATLAS groups library using  LoadPackage( "AtlasRep", false ); g:= AtlasGroup( "3^2.U4(3).D8"); Then you can get $3^2.U_4(3)$ as the second derived group. The two non-isomorphic groups $3.U_4(3)$ can be found as actions (of degree $378$) on subgroups with structure $S_4(3) \times 3$, one of which is a point stabilizer.

Comment: These are very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone is still interested, I have constructed the cover of $U_4(3)$, of order $36\cdot|U_4(3)|$, as a permutation group (and in the construction process have proven that it is unique, up to isomorphism).

This group can be found at https://github.com/hulpke/perfect/tree/main/particulars

Comment: I iteratively built extensions with trivial modules, basically in the process as used for the construction of perfect groups (Hulpke, Alexander(1-COS)
The perfect groups of order up to two million.
Math. Comp.91(2022), no.334, 1007–1017)

Comment: I used this representation to figure out that the $ 3.A_7 $ subgroup of $ SU(6) $ is actually not maximal because it is contained in the subgroup $ 6_1.PSU(4,3) \subset SU(6) $, thanks so much for your help!