# Counting groups based on PSU(4,3)

Tags: finite-groups, characters, gap

How many almost quasisimple extensions of PSU(4,3) are there?

As noted in [Constructing central extensions or Schur cover of U4(3) in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775608/constructing-central-extensions-or-schur-cover-of-u43-in-gap) this group is too large to be in the perfect groups library (the order 3,265,920 is over 2 million) and it has abnormally large Schur Multiplier (36) and large automorphism group ($D_{8}$) so there are many almost quasisimple groups associated with it.

The Atlas only lists these eleven https://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/clas/U43/ :

U4(3)

2.U4(3)

U4(3).2_1

U4(3).4

U4(3).2_2

U4(3).2_3

3_2.U4(3).2_3

3_2.U4(3).2_3'

U4(3):D8

3_2.U4(3):D8

2.U4(3).D8

I know GAP already contains some thing on this list such a CharacterTable("6_1.U4(3).2_2");

Is there a way to convince GAP to print out a list of all groups in the character table library defined by a string that contains "U4(3)" ? Because I guess that would be a
good start. Does GAP character table library even contain all the almost quasisimple groups based on PSU(4,3)?

Comment: I posted a permutation representation of the Schur cover of $U_4(3)$ in an answer under https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775608/constructing-central-extensions-or-schur-cover-of-u43-in-gap/4827195#4827195

Comment: @ahulpke that does look interesting! Also on an unrelated note I noticed that $ A_7, 3.A_7, 6.A_7 $ all have faithful 6d irreps. Is there a story here that's worth asking about? Or is it just a meaningless coincidence and I shouldn't bother making a MSE question?

Comment: oh wait I think I answered my own question the $ A_7 $ is just the standard deleted permutation representation so is a subgroup of $ SO(6) \subset SU(6) $ and then $ 3.A_7 $ is not a subgroup of the compact symplectic group $ Sp(3) \subset SU(6) $ but I think it might be a subgroup of the central product $ \zeta_6 \circ_2 Sp(3) \subset SU(6) $? And then $ 6.A_6 $ is the only Lie primitive one, for example it is the only one that is irreducible in the adjoint representation of $ SU(6) $. Maybe I'll try to find all maximal closed subgroups of $ SU(6) $ that could be fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get groups mapping onto $U_4(3)$, you could use:

```
c:=CharacterTable("U4(3)");
NamesOfFusionSources(c);
```

and eliminate the ones that are subgroups. You could do similarly for `U4(3).2_1` and so on.